# trying to debug Mysql trigger not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a mysql db trigger that I am trying to debug of why its not working.  I am trying to determine when a threshold in the billing usage table is greater then the threshold defined in the billing_tier table.  If the usage table is greater than the tier then insert recored in billing_alert table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Threashold AFTER UPDATE ON billing_usage
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE total_threashold bigint;
DECLARE tier_cd bigint;

SET @tier_cd := NEW.tier_cd;
SET @total_threashold := (select total_threashold from billing_tier 
where tier_cd = @tier_cd);

IF NEW.total_data > @total_threashold THEN
     -- Only used for testing
  INSERT INTO billing_alert (organization_id, user_id, create_ts) VALUES(99999, 'triggerFired',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You should avoid giving declared variables the same names as columns (tier_cd) also declared variables and user defined variables (those with and @ prefix) are discrete (ie total_threshold is a separate variable from @total_threshold)